# Swift - CoreData NSPredicate - Fetch Children of parent

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to fetch all the children of a parent.

In my case the parent is an entity AgendaEvent which has many AgendaDate (the children).

so Here's my function:

```
 func getRelatedAgendaEvent(event: AgendaEvent) ->NSFetchRequest<AgendaDate> {
    // create a fetch request that will retrieve all the AgendaDate.
    let fetchRquest = NSFetchRequest<AgendaDate>(entityName: "AgendaDate")

    // set the predicate to only keep AgendaDate related with the AgendaEvent selected
    fetchRquest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parent == %@", event)

    return fetchRquest
}
```

and I use this in didselectRow for a tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var eventToPass: AgendaEvent!
    var eventDateToPassArray: [AgendaDate]!

    eventToPass = myTempEvents[indexPath.row]
    eventDateToPassArray = try! context.fetch(getRelatedAgendaEvent(event: eventToPass))
    DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "EventToModify", sender: eventToPass)
    }
}
```

}

I'm trying to use eventDateToPassArray in a segue.
The error i'm getting is:

```
keypath parent not found in entity <NSSQLEntity AgendaDate id=1> with userInfo of (null)
```

I'm not sure this is the right path. I am trying to update a NSSet (AgendaDate) when the user edit an AgendaEvent. So basically while updating and AgendaEvent the user also updates the date in the related AgendaData NSSet.

Thank you!

-------------UPDDATE

Martin you mean this:

AgendaDate+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
extension AgendaDate {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<AgendaDate> {
    return NSFetchRequest<AgendaDate>(entityName: "AgendaDate")
}

@NSManaged public var agendaDates: NSDate?
@NSManaged public var agendaEvents: AgendaEvent?
```

}

AgendaDate+CoreDataClass.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(AgendaDate)
public class AgendaDate: NSManagedObject {

}
```

Comment: You assign a value to eventDateToPassArray, but never *use* it.

Comment: @MartinR i know.... i've printed just to see the results..but i get that error

Comment: Show how `AgendaDate` is defined. And where *exactly* do you get the error?

Comment: @MartinR i get the error when i select the AgendaEvent in the table. How is defined you mean the object or in the controller?

Comment: Show the class/extension code where the properties of AgendaDate are defined.

Comment: @MartinR sorry... i'm new to this... i've created it in interface builder and it does not automatically create any extension or class...i can add a picture of the model in interface builder

Comment: @MartinR I have updated question

Comment: It seems that you nowhere defined a "parent" property in AgendaDate (which explains the error message).

Comment: but i defined the relationship... i guess i have so much to learn still... i thought the parent was the relationship between the 2 entities...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155153/discussion-between-martin-r-and-marco).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key path used in the fetch request must match the actual name 
of the Core Data relationship, in your case "agendaEvents",
there is no implicit "parent" relationship:

```
fetchRquest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "agendaEvents == %@", event)
```

Even better, use `#keyPath` and the `%K` expansion

```
fetchRquest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@",
                                    #keyPath(AgendaDate.agendaEvents), event)
```

so the that *compiler* checks the validity of the key path.
This helps to avoid using unknown key paths or typos.

Note that a better relationship name would be "agendaEvent"
or just "event", with the singular form for a to-one relationship.

Comment: I think you are missing a parenthesis. You open for `NSPredicate` and `#keypath`, but only close once